# Error saving the core data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I have an error while trying to save the date core . The error is occurring in the lines that I give a setValue the item.
The error appears in " ***item.setValue (id, Forkey : " id " )*** " someone can tell me what can be ? thanks

json is a json object of a request

Error: Argument labels '(_:, forkey:)' do not match any available overloads

```
func saveJson(json: AnyObject){       

 do{

        let dictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json as! NSData, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
        let name = dictionary!["name"] as? String
        let id = dictionary!["id"] as? Int
        let email = dictionary!["email"] as! String
        let password = dictionary!["password"] as! String
        let verifyCode = dictionary!["verify_code"] as! String

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        item.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        item.setValue(id, forkey: "id")
        item.setValue(email, forkey: "email")
        item.setValue(verifyCode, forkey: "verifyCode")
        let val = item.valueForKey("email") as! String

        print("Valorrr",val)

        do{
            try managedContext.save()

        }catch{
            print("error")
        }


    } catch{

    }



}
```

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://softwarejuancarlos.com/2015/12/19/swift-2-examples-9-core-data-create-get-update-and-remove-entities/ . It's should help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap ***id*** in an NSNumber to use it with the method `setValue`

Try:

```
let id = dictionary!["id"] as? NSNumber
```